# Is there a series that converges for finitely many terms but not convergent as limit goes to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a series $\{a_k\} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^N {a_k}$ that converges for $N < \infty$ but fails to converge for $\lim k \to \infty$?

In other words, is there a reason why we should check the closure property of a space (to ensure that $\lim k \to \infty$ is convergent) if all finite many terms are convergent?

Comment: Try $a_n=1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Please give a meaning to "converges for $N<\infty$".

Comment: What do you mean by "converges for $N < \infty$ but fails to converge for $\lim_{k \to \infty}$"?  Do you mean that it converges up until some arbitrarily large but finite $N$, and then after that it does whatever it pleases?  If so, then the answer is yes, but in a completely uninteresting way: A series $\{a_k\}$ where $a_k = \max\{k, N\}$ does that.  If you mean that it converges for *any* finite $N$, then the answer is no, provided "converges for any finite $N$" is interpreted in a straightforward way, for a similarly uninteresting reason: That's just the definition of convergence.

Comment: We say "the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k$ converges", when the sequence of the partial sums $\left\{s_N\right\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges for "$N\rightarrow\infty$". Each element $s_N$ of the series is finite, also when the series does not converge. So I think there are some basic facts about sequences and series which you did not understand and/or are mixing up.

Comment: Did you mean to say let a sequence $b_{n,N}= \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_{k,n}   $?

Comment: Sorry, but this question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you learned this in your course or textbook, but the definition of convergence of a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is that there is some $l$ such that, for *any* $\epsilon > 0$, the terms of the sequence will eventually get $\epsilon$-close to $l$ - that is, after a certain index $N_\epsilon$, the terms $a_n$ for $n > N_\epsilon$ will be no more than $\epsilon$ distant from $l$. This means that $l - \epsilon < a_n < l + \epsilon$, which is the same as $- \epsilon < a_n - l < \epsilon$, or $|a_n - l| < \epsilon$, if $n > N_\epsilon$.

For a given sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, we define $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ as the limit of the sequence $\{s_N\}$, where $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$, as $N$ goes to infinity - ***provided this limit exists***. (We call $s_N$ "the $N$th partial sum of $\{a_n\}$".)

So, to answer your first question, **the definition of convergence doesn't apply to finite sequences**. Basically, we're not concerned with what the first few terms do - we're concerned with what large enough terms do (the $n$th terms, for $n > N_\epsilon$). It's similar to how the notion of the limit of a function at a point isn't based on finitely many values the function takes, but all of the values it takes near a certain point - and whether they approach a certain value as you get closer to that point.

Answer (score 1):

*All* the finite terms are *always* finite and thus *always* "converge".  *ALL* series "converge" for finite N.  A finite sum will add to a specific non infinite value.  Even  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^N k$ has a finite value for all N.

Although it's not called "converging". It's simply called "having a finite value".

If you want to get technical, here is a proof.  If the series is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^N a_k$.  Let $  x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^N a_k$.   Then for all $n \ge N$, $|x - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k|= 0$ because there are no $a_k$ for n > N.